Why is rtime_last_played not being returned for most Steam profiles via the Steam Web API?
I'm in the process of building an app for gamers and am attempting to import and sort games from different platforms, one of which is Steam.
Using the SteamAPI, I'm able to access data just fine by calling the getownedgames endpoint for some users, and it returns the following:

{'appid': 553850, 'name': 'HELLDIVERS™ 2', 'playtime_forever': 7, 'img_icon_url': 'c3dff088e090f81d6e3d88eabbb67732647c69cf', 'has_community_visible_stats': True, 'playtime_windows_forever': 7, 'playtime_mac_forever': 0, 'playtime_linux_forever': 0, 'playtime_deck_forever': 0, 'rtime_last_played': 1707493650, 'content_descriptorids': [2, 5], 'playtime_disconnected': 0}

However, for many users, each game only returns the following:

{'appid': 2050650, 'name': 'Resident Evil 4', 'playtime_forever': 1311, 'img_icon_url': '817358b8013c55831ea10d031ef9c0b151110826', 'has_community_visible_stats': True, 'content_descriptorids': [2, 5]}

There is no difference in privacy settings between the 2 users, and the last played dates are publicly visible on their profile pages. I cannot figure out at all why, for some users, this is being brought back, and for others, it isn't brought back for any of their games. Also, note that the different platform playtimes are also not brought over for a huge number of users.
I have tried this across several accounts and ensured each has public privacy settings. I have tried to access it using both the Python Steam API and HTTP requests directly into the API. I continue to get the problem for the same users where the last played date is not being returned.

After some digging I think it return only rtime_last_played when called with the SteamID of the account which hold the API Key
Valve seem to have changed the privacy rules for that recently, because that was working like 6 months ago
To add to it, if you go to any public profile on the Steam community in the HTML it does not show anymore the last played value

Ahhh that would make sense tbf! Thank you so much. It's a massive shame they've made that change as it was such a useful thing to have access to; I'm now having to use the last earned achievement date as a sort of stand-in for last-played, but if you've got all the achievements and have for a while, this is obviously highly inaccurate.

It think there must be a possibility left (maybe with SteamKit2 instead of the API), since website like Exophase can still get the last played value (even for games with no achievements)
I have just tested it myself, launching Assetto Corsa Competizione (0 achievements) on Steam, Exophase have fetch the correct last played value (no idea how)
In the HTML you can still get the last 3 games played (in the profile overview of steam and not in the "All games" tab)
